# Url Routing Asp.net from hierarchical tree of pages stored in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-routing

Ok

I have a bunch of html pages stored in a mssql database. Each row has:

- ID
- PageTitle
- Page Html Content
- ParentId

ParentId is there so i can create a hierarchical tree of pages.

Currently i am using this line of code in order to access the pages...

```
routes.MapPageRoute("front", "{PageTitle}", "~/front.aspx");
```

Which then causes a redirect to front.aspx so i can then use:

```
Page.RouteData.Values["PageTitle"].ToString()
```

In order to grab what i need so i can display the appropriate page in the browser.

However, can anyone suggest how i would amend 'routes.MapPageRoute' so it supports an infinate hierarchical tree like i have in my database. Essentially i want to be able to type a url like: http://localhost/PageOne/SubPageOfPageOne etc

Answer (score 0):

Changed:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("front", "{PageTitle}", "~/front.aspx");
```

to this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("front", "{*PageTitle}", "~/front.aspx");
```

this pulls everything that is in the url (past the domain the name)...

then i used the split function to recursively get each node so i could check if it exists.